# Pact dependency stopping tests being run

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, pact

`Pact` depends on a package called `make-error-cause`.  In its `index.js` it declares a method, then a var immediately afterwards with the same name.

Jest/Typescript does not like this.  NOTHING we do will allow our test to run when ran with `Jest`, we continuously get this error:

`SyntaxError: /Users/user1234/Documents/Workspace/aws_stack/node_modules/make-error-cause/dist/index.js: Identifier 'makeErrorCause' has already been declared (12:4)`

And this is the snippet of code from `make-error-cause`'s `index.js`:

```
var makeError = require('make-error');
function makeErrorCause(value, _super) {
    if (_super === void 0) { _super = makeErrorCause.BaseError; }
    return makeError(value, _super);
}
var makeErrorCause;
```

We have tried `@pact-foundation/pact` and `pact-jest` both have the same problem.

Versions:
"@pact-foundation/pact": "^9.10.0"
"typescript": "^3.8.3"
 "jest": "24.9.0"
"ts-jest": "^24.3.0"
"@types/jest": "^24.0.25"

If i change `var makeErrorCause;` to `var makeErrorCause2;`, the problem goes away.  Obviously this won't work for anyone else trying to build it....

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that sucks! This issue should belong at https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-js. Looks to be fatal - could you please raise there along with a repro we can use?

Our builds (both projects) do test Jest in every commit, so it's likely a combination of versions of dependencies we need to sort through.

Comment: Ah brilliant, I will do my best to put together a working example by the end of today.  I'm going to try to implement with mocha for now, with the aim of moving back to jest in line with out projects.  Just on the version thing... I've looked at this example (https://github.com/YOU54F/jest-pact-typescript) and copied every jest/typescript dependency I could find, same error.  Maybe I'm missing one...

Comment: Sorry - we'll get to the bottom of it, I promise!

Comment: They never got to the bottom of it.

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-js/issues/606, the issue was relating to a jest config problem:

```
  preset: 'react-native',
  // transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!(react-native|uilib)/)'], ## uncomment this, it's fine.
 //  transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/uilib/']    ## if I uncomment this, it will fail
```